# Pausing and resuming UIView animation with alpha doesn't work when user presses Home button

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

**Question:**

> 1. How can I pause a nested UIView animation that animates alpha/opacity when the user presses the Home button and returns back to the app?
> 2. What have I missed in the code below? Thank you.

---

**Background:**

I have a simple nested UIView animation that adjusts the alpha of a view slowly at different times from `alpha =  0` to `alpha =  1` over 1 minute.

When a user presses the Home button, the UIView animation does not pause, so when the app resumes, the UIView animation fasts forward to the very end of the animation, the alpha changes instantly from 0 to 1 on resuming the app.

*So, I’m trying to pause the UIView animation when the user presses the device Home button and temporarily suspends the app.*

I have a function that pauses the animation (`pauseLayer`) and then recommences the animation (`resumeLayer`). These two functions work great when calling them from a `UIButton`. It pauses the `alpha` and resumes the animation as expected. (However, if the Home button is pressed while the animation is paused, when it resumes the alpha changes instantly from 0 to 1.)

When I try calling the `pauseLayer` when the user presses the Home button (receiving the `WillResignActive` notification), and then returns back to the app (receiving the `WillEnterForeground` notification), the animation doesn’t pause and resume, instead the alpha changes instantly from 0 to 1 on resuming the app.

It would seem it should work, but it doesn’t.

---

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myView2: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setNotifications()
        myAnimation()
    }

    @IBAction func myPauseButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let layer = self.view.layer
        pauseLayer(layer)
    }

    @IBAction func myResumeButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let layer = self.view.layer
        resumeLayer(layer)
    }

    func setNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.WillEnterForeground(_:)), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.WillResignActive(_:)), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func WillEnterForeground(notification : NSNotification) {
        let layer = self.view.layer
        resumeLayer(layer)
    }

    func WillResignActive(notification : NSNotification) {
        let layer = self.view.layer
        pauseLayer(layer)
    }

    func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
        layer.speed = 0.0
        layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }

    func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
        layer.speed = 1.0
        layer.timeOffset = 0.0
        layer.beginTime = 0.0
        let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil) - pausedTime
        layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }

    func myAnimation() {
        self.myView1.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(15, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.myView1.alpha = 0.1
            }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(15, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
                    self.myView1.alpha = 0.2
                    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(30, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
                            self.myView1.alpha = 1
                            }, completion: nil)
                })
        })

        self.myView2.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(15, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.myView2.alpha = 0.1
            }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(15, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
                    self.myView2.alpha = 0.2
                    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(30, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
                            self.myView2.alpha = 1
                            }, completion: nil)
                })
        })
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If I add `if (finished) {` to each section, then press the Home button, then return to the app, the animation only progresses to the next section and stops, no further. This is better, but the issue then is that the `resumeLayer` doesn’t seem to work, so the animation remains stopped and doesn’t continue.

```
        self.myView2.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(15, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .LayoutSubviews, .AllowUserInteraction, .BeginFromCurrentState], animations: {
            self.myView2.alpha = 0.1
            }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
                if (finished) {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(15, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .LayoutSubviews, .AllowUserInteraction, .BeginFromCurrentState], animations: {
                    self.myView2.alpha = 0.2
                    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
                        if (finished) {
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(30, delay: 0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .LayoutSubviews, .AllowUserInteraction, .BeginFromCurrentState], animations: {
                            self.myView2.alpha = 1
                            }, completion: nil)
                        }
                })
                }
        })
```

Comment: Maybe instead of UIApplicationWillEnterForeground you should use UIApplicationDidBecomeActive

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work @Calimari328 but thanks, though, I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use UIView Animation to accomplish a simple fade.

You could use an Timer object and a little Math to manually animate it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = colorScheme.red

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didResignActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
    }

    func didBecomeActive() {
        if case min_t..<max_t = t {
            beginAnimation(at: t)
        }
    }

    func didResignActive() {
        _ = pauseAnimation()
    }


    var t = TimeInterval(0.0)
    let min_t = TimeInterval(0)
    let max_t = TimeInterval(100)
    let delta = TimeInterval(0.1)
    var timerObj: Timer?

    func timer(_ aTimer: Timer) {
        if t < max_t {
            // Using a parabola
            view.alpha = CGFloat(0.0001 * t * t)
        } else {
            _ = pauseAnimation()
        }
        t = t + 1
    }

    func beginAnimation(at t: TimeInterval = 0) {
        self.t = t
        timerObj = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: delta, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func pauseAnimation() -> TimeInterval {
        timerObj?.invalidate()
        return t
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        beginAnimation()
    }
}
```

However, there is a possibility that your application is actually more complicated and your example is a simplification.  Well, how about this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.WillEnterForeground(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.WillResignActive(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
    }

    func WillEnterForeground(notification : NSNotification) {
        if let timegap = endDate?.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            , timegap < duration {
            beginAnimation(with: timegap/duration)
        }
    }

    func WillResignActive(notification : NSNotification) {
        let layer = self.view.layer
        layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }

    var duration = TimeInterval(10)
    var percentComplete = 0.0
    var startDate: Date = Date()
    var endDate: Date?

    func beginAnimation(with percent: Double = 0.0) {
        view.alpha = CGFloat(percent)

        startDate = Date()
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration * (1 - percent)
            , delay: 0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.calculationModeLinear,
              animations: {
                if percent < 0.2 {
                    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                        self.view.alpha = 0.1
                    })
                }
                if percent < 0.5 {
                    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.2, relativeDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                        self.view.alpha = 0.2
                    })
                }

                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                    self.view.alpha = 1.0
                })
        }) { (b: Bool) in
            if b == false {
                self.endDate = Date()
                if let timegap = self.endDate?.timeIntervalSince(self.startDate)
                    , timegap < self.duration {
                    self.view.alpha = CGFloat(timegap / self.duration)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        beginAnimation()
    }

}
```

The main idea is to get the time before the animation starts and the time when it ends.  The completion will tell us true if the animation was successful, but if the user presses the home button the completion block will tell us false.  If it is false we can capture the date and find out the time difference and calculate the percent of completion.  then we can use the percentage to determine the amount of time left.

Hope that helps

Comment: This gives some ideas. Thanks. I was hoping to retain `UIView.animateWithDuration` as keyframe animations can be limiting sometimes. The original method works when the button is pressed, but putting the app into the background interrupts that method unfortunately. You are correct, there is a more elaborate animation than that put here. However this concise version throws the exact same issue with regards to alpha animations. The concise example here is to keep it all simple to follow. What I don't understand is why the animation fast forwards in the background when each part has not completed?